# Can't connect to mysql DB. DriverManager error. Java + netBeans

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

No idea what I'm doing wrong, why DriverManager is underlined in red and NetBeans suggests to create a DriverManager Class...

```
public class regularcustomerreg extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form regularcustomerreg
     */
    public regularcustomerreg() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    
    public void Connect() {
        
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lutonhotel", "root", "");
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(regularcustomerreg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Just extend Exception e and print e.printStackTrace() and let me know the error stack trace. Kindly check if mysql jar version is in place and also check if you are manually able to connect to db with the above parameters before connecting through java.

Comment: Do you have `import java.sql.DriverManager;` in your class? Or are you by any chance using a modular project (i.e. you have a `module-info.java` in the root of your sources), and if so, does it contain `requires java.sql;`?